# Specifying a host address for a UDP server?

Tags: node.js, udp

So I have the option to specify an address as well as a port when setting up as a UDP server.

According to the documentation, if no address is specified then the UDP server binds to `0.0.0.0:port`. The documentation says the following: `If address is not specified, the OS will try to listen on all addresses`.

Why would I (or why would I not) specify a host to bind to? Is it for if you have multiple network cards and you only want to listen on one - so I would specify the ip of the network card I wish to listen on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option is for if you have multiple IP addresses on one machine, and you don't want to use all the addresses for binding. If you were to bind on `0.0.0.0` for port 80, you'd be using port 80 on all those addresses. By specifying an address you restrict binding to one address and port.